# Why does the new feature "binary literals" start with 0b instead of being suffixed?

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-6.0

The next **C#** version is planned (*April 2014*) to have binary literals as you can see in the [Language Features Status of Roslyn project](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20feature%20status&version=15).

The example in  that page is like this:

```
0b00000100
```

So you probably will use like this:

```
var myBynaryLiteral = 0b00000100;
```

I want to understand why they choose to prefix this with `0b` instead of use a letter  in the end like they did with `double`, `float`, `decimal` and so on.

```
double a = 1d;
float b = 1f;
decimal c = 1m;
```

Comment: Suffixes are related to type (`f`, `m`), prefixes are related to radix (`0b`, `0x`).

Comment: Can you explain more @FrédéricHamidi? Never used haxadecimal literals but looks like it's what you meant by `0x`. It's a solid point.

Comment: @Vitor: Octal is base 8, hexadecimal is base 16.  (Octal used to be fairly common but nowadays you don't see it much.)  In hexadecimal, you use the digits 0-9, A for 10, B for 11, and so on up to F for 15. The advantage of hex is that a byte can be represented by two digits (and a half-byte or "nybble" by a single digit).  For example, `0x77` is `0111 0111` (or `0b01110111`).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Integer literals possess two varying properties: their types, which can be specified with suffixes like `L` or `UL`, and their radices (called "forms" in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674.aspx)), which can be specified with prefixes like `0x` and now `0b`.

Specifying a type was always done through a suffix, and specifying a radix was always done through a prefix, so it makes sense to keep the same convention. In addition, you can combine both specifiers.

For instance:

```
0b00101010UL
```

Would denote the literal `42`, stored as an unsigned long, and expressed in radix 2.

Comment: How would this work when expressing a float which began life an an integral value, i.e. float val = 0x0FF0f; - Spot the issue? - Presumably Roslyn will not allow floats to be represented as hex?

Comment: @series0ne, that's not only Roslyn, no version of C# allows you to use the `0x` prefix with something else than integer literals. You cannot apply it to float literals in the first place.